# then() function of Promise.all executing before promises are finished - Ionic/Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, caching, ionic-framework, promise

I am setting up caching for the first time with `ionic`. Here is the code:

```
listProducts(): Promise < any > {
    let cacheKey = 'products';
    this.cache.removeItem(cacheKey);
    let promises_array:Array<any> = [];
    let results;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.cache.getItem(cacheKey).catch(() => {
            this.list = this.af.list('/products');
            this.subscription5 = this.list.subscribe(items => {
                for (let x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
                    promises_array.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(items[x].customMetadata) + ":   this is the customdata (((()()()()()");
                        let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('/settings/' + items[x].customMetadata.username + '/profilepicture.png');
                        storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
                            console.log(url + "in download url !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                            items[x].customMetadata.profilepic = url;
                        }).catch((e) => {
                            console.log("in caught url !!!!!!!$$$$$$$!!");
                            items[x].customMetadata.profilepic = 'assets/blankprof.png';
                        });
                        //this.startAtKey = item.$key;
                        this.productListArray.push(items[x].customMetadata);
                    }));
                };
            })
            results = Promise.all(promises_array);
            results.then(() => {
                //setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(this.productListArray) + " value value vlaue productlistarray");
                this.productListArray.reverse();
                return this.cache.saveItem(cacheKey, this.productListArray);
                //}, 3000);
            })
        }).then(data => {
            console.log("Saved data: ", data);
            resolve();
        })
    })
}
```

Basically the line `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.productListArray) + " value value vlaue productlistarray");` prints an empty array - `[]`. There should be data in this variable because the code shouldn't execute before all of the promises are done. You'll notice I have a `setTimeout` commented out - when I comment it in, it works - but this is obviously not an acceptable solution, I'm just showing that its a timing problem with the promises. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies in this line

```
this.list.subscribe(items => {
```

Basically, list is still fetching when

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.productListArray) + " value...
```

is run. So I expect `promises_array` is empty (you can check that out).

You can sort that out by mapping `list` (either map() or flatMap(), need to check which) into an array of promises instead of pushing individual promises in.

I think this is the map (or flatMap) code, but it needs testing. Note, lots of returns are required at every indent level.

```
const promises_array = this.list.map(items => {
  return items.map(item => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(items[x].customMetadata) + ":   this is the customdata (((()()()()()");
      let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('/settings/' + items[x].customMetadata.username + '/profilepicture.png');
      return storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
        console.log(url + "in download url !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        items[x].customMetadata.profilepic = url;
      }).catch((e) => {
        console.log("in caught url !!!!!!!$$$$$$$!!");
        items[x].customMetadata.profilepic = 'assets/blankprof.png';
      });
      this.productListArray.push(items[x].customMetadata);
    }));    
  })
}
Promise.all(promises_array)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.productListArray) + " value value vlaue productlistarray");
    this.productListArray.reverse();
    this.cache.saveItem(cacheKey, this.productListArray);
})
```

Comment: great thanks...i actually have used this technique elsewhere in my app...ill try it - im pretty sure ur right, i kind of remember having this problem before